# Prove that: the center of any group is characteristic subgroup .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be any group , $Z(G)$ is the center of the group $G$ , prove that :
$\forall \tau \in Aut(G) , \tau [(Z(G)] = Z(G)$

My first trial was to prove that the center of any group is the unique subgroup of its order hence is a characteristic . but i found a counterexample easily which is $D_8$ the Dihedrial group of order $8$ ( i use the notation $D_{2n}$ )

So , any hints ?

Comment: Try applying the definitions directly. There is not really any trick here.

Comment: In fact, a more general statement is true: given $Z_i(G)$ in the upper central series of a group $G, Z_i(G)$ is characteristic in $G$, with the special case that $Z_1(G) = Z(G)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you show that for any $x\in Z(G)$ and $y\in G$, $\tau(x)\tau(y)=\tau(y)\tau(x)$? This will say $\tau(x)$ commutes with every element of $G$ (since $y$ was arbitrary), thus $\tau(x)\in Z(G)$. This shows containment in one direction, can you show containment in the other direction now?

Comment: Your answer shows $\tau(Z) \subset Z$?

Comment: @Al: yes.... that is exactly what my answer says based on the fact that it says $x\in Z(G)\Rightarrow\tau(x)\in Z(G)$.

Answer (score 4):

- Is every element of $\tau(Z(G))$ central in $G$? (Translation: is $\tau(Z(G)) \subseteq Z(G)$? The answer should be "yes".)
- Is anything else central in $G$ that isn't already in $\tau(Z(G))$? (Translation: is $\tau(Z(G)) \subsetneq Z(G)$? The answer should be "no". Otherwise, what happens when you hit it with $\tau^{-1}$?)

Comment: Of course, having proved that $\sigma(Z(G)) \subseteq Z(G)$ for any automorphism $\sigma$, you can just let $\sigma = \tau$ for one direction and $\sigma = \tau^{-1}$ for the other.

Answer (score -2):

consider that any Automorphism preserves the order, means order of Z(G) = order of τ(Z(G)).