# Center of a normal subgroup is also a normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, intuition, alternative-proof, normal-subgroups

If $K$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$, then the center $Z(K)$ of $K$ is also a normal subgroup of $G$.

I want to prove this statement. But without using characteristic subgroups and automorphisms. Since in our course we did not learn yet. I hope there is another proof that only uses conjugation, (normal) subgroups, and center/centralizers.

Comment: You can start from the definition of "center" and definition of "normal subgroup".

Comment: Thanks @Nobody, but I know that primary stuff. I know Z(G), is a normal subgroup of G.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that the center of a group is a normal subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66052/prove-that-the-center-of-a-group-is-a-normal-subgroup)

Comment: No. It is not the same question. Please read carefully

Comment: The following might be considered as an abstract duplicate: [If $N$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$, and $M$ is a characteristic subgroup of $N$, then $M$ is a normal subgroup of G.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647066/386889)

Comment: I don't know characteristic subgroups, we didn't learn that in the course. I need a more basic explanation, a different approach.

Comment: Well it is a good opportunity to learn this convenient notion.Next time please do not just ask. Show some work. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Oh, ok. You are right. I am new here, sorry. Also, thanks for the answer. I will do some research

Comment: The approach I gave in my answer is much simpler than what is in the linked post.

Comment: [Prove that: the center of any group is characteristic subgroup .](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/430882/386889)

Answer (score 2):

Let $z \in Z(H)$ and let $g \in G$. Since $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $z \in H$, we know that $gzg^{-1} \in H$. We claim that $gzg^{-1} \in Z(H)$. Let $h \in H$. We want to show that $hgzg^{-1}=gzg^{-1}h$. Since $H$ is normal in $G$, we know that $g^{-1}hg=h'$ for some $h' \in H$.

Try to take it from here.

Comment: We have $g^{-1}hg=h'$. Multiply both sides by $g^{-1}$ on the right.

Comment: I guess, I found the answer thanks to you. Showing $hgzg^{−1}=gzg^{−1}h$ is a good simplification. I also used the lemma $gzg^{-1}ghg^{-1} = ghg^{-1}gzg^{-1}$. Which is more critical, I guess. It indicates, after a transformation action on both $h$ and $z$, $z'$ still commutes. Then showing your idea is simple because $ghg^{-1}$ is just another element of $H$.

Comment: I guess, I used unintentionally the concept of automorphism. Am I right? I have not covered that topic yet.

Comment: Did you get your question answered? I didn't see your question until now.